# I want user can change website language using drop-down without login but if they log in website should translate in their saved language preference

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I am using a Django website in which a user can change their language using a drop-down menu. I use Django i18n for the translation of the website. Now problem is that I want a user can visit some pages of the website without login and they can change the language using a drop-down. But when a user logs in, the language of the website should change to the default language of that user's we store in their porifle section. How can I achieve this?

language_form.html

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="/i18n/setlang/?next={% url 'homepage' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="language" style="padding: 4px 3px;">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
        {% for language in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ language.0 }}"{% if language.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %} ">
                {{ language.1 }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% for lang in aLANGUAGES %}
        {{lang.list}}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Change language" style="padding: 3px 3px; margin-right: 10px;">
  </form>
```

The above code is my drop-down form for the select languages but I want user can select their preferred language in the profile section and that will be enabled automatically when they logged in.

Comment: You need a column in the database , where you save user lang preference, and on login, setting the default value from database

Comment: I had set up everything described by you. But I want to know how to save language to the user's language preference models' user_language field when the user login via OAuth. I am describing the process: 1). user goto homepage where he selects a language from the drop-down that is saved in their session cookies and when they log in via OAuth that should be saved in user_language field how to accomplish this functionality.